# Keep the tensorflow estimator in memory while waiting for live prediction inputs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a trained estimator which I use to do live prediction as new input data comes in.

At the beginning of the code I instantiate the estimator:

```py
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir="{}/model_dir_{}".format(script_dir, 3))
```

Then in a loop, every time I get enough new data for a prediction I do:

```py
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.array([sample.normalized.input_data])},
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)
predictions = estimator.predict(
    input_fn=predict_input_fn,
)
```

Every time I do this I get these tensorflow messages in the console:

> 2018-04-21 16:01:08.401319: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1195] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/fgervais/tf/model_dir_3/model.ckpt-103712

It seems that the whole GPU detection process and model loading is done again on every predictions.

Is there a way to keep the model loaded in memory in between live inputs so I get a better prediction rate?

Comment: I don't know why people down vote this. I am having the exact same issue, and this solution is very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this is to use a [predictor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895#issuecomment-383698729).

In the specific context of the question it would be done like this:

```py
def serving_input_fn():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3500], name='x')
    inputs = {'x': x }

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir="{}/model_dir_{}/model.ckpt-103712".format(script_dir, 3))

estimator_predictor = tf.contrib.predictor.from_estimator(
                            estimator, serving_input_fn)

p = estimator_predictor(
        {"x": np.array(sample.normalized.input_data)})
```